# Macro to open a excel in shared path

Tags: vba, excel

Hi all i am able to open any excel files in my desktop. but i am not able to open a excel which is in shared path. file not found error message is displayed
Need your help...!!!
The path starts with two backslashes "\..\.....\"

```
Sub open_hari()
    Dim r As Long
    For r = 1 To 10
        If Cells(r, 1).Value <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=Sheet1.Cells(r, 1).Value
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: opening UNC paths _does_ work.  Check that the entries in you sheet are in fact valid paths (try copy/paste into Explorer)

Comment: Check if you have necessary access to drive. Try to open the file manually and see if its working for you.

Comment: Hey santhos, manually i am bale to open the path. Chris, I copy pasted the path in explorer its working fine

Comment: This code didn't work for me until I took out the `Sheet1` at the start of `Filename:=`

Answer (score 0):

I had no problem opening a file of the form `\\myshare\etc\file.xlsx` from VBA. So I tried running your code, and it worked for me up to the point that it found a non-empty cell... but once I found a file and opened it, the code automatically started looking at cells in the new workbook (I had a file name in row 6; that file was opened, and then the code looked at row 7 in the newly opened file. This did not have a valid file name in it).

If that is the cause of your problem, the solution would be to set the range before you start scrolling through it... :

```
Sub open_hari()
    Dim myCells
    Dim c
    Set myCells = Range(Sheet1.[A1], Sheet1.[A10]).Cells
    For Each c In myCells
        If c.Value <> "" Then
            Workbooks.Open Filename:=c.Value
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

This solved the problem for me...

Incidentally, you could add a line

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Just before the

```
Workbooks.Open
```

statement. That way, if a cell contains a non-valid file name (but isn't empty), the code will keep right on going. That doesn't help you figure out that you have a problem with your code, so it's usually a good idea not to do that until it's thoroughly debugged. This problem of looking at a different sheet would be completely invisible to you if you'd had that error trap enabled.